# Best algorithm/data structure for a continually updated priority queue

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, set, priority-queue

I need to frequently find the minimum value object in a set that's being continually updated. I need to have a priority queue type of functionality. What's the best algorithm or data structure to do this? I was thinking of having a sorted tree/heap, and every time the value of an object is updated, I can remove the object, and re-insert it into the tree/heap. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: What type are the values?

Comment: The values used for comparison are just ints.

Comment: How many items? What's the range of the values?

Comment: Increase- and decrease-key operations can often be supported by moving the items around in the tree, instead of removing and inserting them anew. This might have the same asymptotical performance but can make aa large difference in practice if the values only change slightly

Comment: The number of objects is on the order of 10,000. The range of values is from 0 to ~100.

Comment: @user3473949 Have you tried using buckets instead of a priority queue?  I mean just storing for every value a linked list of items that have that value. Modify-key is then just a matter of removing the item from one list and adding it to another. If you keep a pointer to the minimum non-empty bucket you can find it in O(1). Maintaining that pointer when the bucket it points to gets empty might be slightly more costly, but it's just a linear scan over at most 100 pointers that easily fit into L1, so that's very cheap as well (and maybe the min doesn't change too often in your scenario)

Comment: @NiklasB.: Delete-min can be sped-up by using a (bit-packed) vector of boolean values stating which buckets are non-empty, and quickly finding the least significant set bit in it.

Comment: @Gassa Or that, but my guess is that would not even be noticably faster if the min doesn't change *very* often. 100 pointer scans is the absolute worst case, usually you will probably only do a few increments

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks, your solution seems to be the most efficient one for my circumstances. It blows things like a Fibonacci Heap out of the water in this case. If you put your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: You say "being continually updated", but the kinds of updates matter enormously.  Inserts?  DeleteMins?  Arbitrary deletes?  Merge?  DecreaseKey?  IncreaseKey?  Others?

Comment: @ChrisOkasaki : "Updated" means that the value that the object is being sorted on changes.

Answer (score 1):

A binary heap is hard to beat for simplicity, but it has the disadvantage that *decrease-key* takes O(n) time. I know, the standard references say that it's O(log n), but first you have to find the item. That's O(n) for a standard binary heap.

By the way, if you do decide to use a binary heap, changing an item's priority doesn't require a remove and re-insert. You can change the item's priority in-place and then either bubble it up or sift it down as required.

If the performance of *decrease-key* is important, a good alternative is a [pairing heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap), which is theoretically slower than a Fibonacci heap, but is much easier to implement and in practice is faster than the Fibonacci heap due to lower constant factors. In practice, pairing heap compares favorably with binary heap, and outperforms binary heap if you do a lot of *decrease-key* operations.

You could also marry a binary heap and a dictionary or hash map, and keep the dictionary updated with the position of the item in the heap. This gives you faster *decrease-key* at the cost of more memory and increased constant factors for the other operations.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Usual_implementation):

> To improve performance, priority queues typically use a heap as their
>   backbone, giving O(log n) performance for inserts and removals, and
>   O(n) to build initially. Alternatively, when a self-balancing binary
>   search tree is used, insertion and removal also take O(log n) time,
>   although building trees from existing sequences of elements takes O(n
>   log n) time; this is typical where one might already have access to
>   these data structures, such as with third-party or standard libraries.

If you are looking for a better way, there must be something special about the objects in your priority queue. For example, if the keys are numbers from 1 to 10, a countsort-based approach may outperform the usual ones.

Comment: Actually there are heaps with O(1) decrease-key (not sure about increase), but I guess those have constant factors that make them impractical

Comment: @NiklasB.: Yeah, there are [Fibonacci heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap#Summary_of_running_times) for example, but from what I heard, they are impractical due to the large constant factor.

Answer (score 0):

If your application looks anything like repeatedly choosing the next scheduled event in a discrete event simulation, you might consider the options listed in e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_event_simulation and http://www.acm-sigsim-mskr.org/Courseware/Fujimoto/Slides/FujimotoSlides-03-FutureEventList.pdf. The later summarizes results from different implementations in this domain, including many of the options considered in other comments and answers - and a search will find a number of papers in this area. Priority queue overhead really does make some difference in how many times real time you can get your simulation to run - and if you wish to simulate something that takes weeks of real time this can be important.